# SVG картинку как фон вне блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Каким образом можно подложить SVG картинки как на макете (изображение макета прикреплено)? SVG картинки это всё кроме текста, а именно оранжевые, фиолетовые, голубые пятна и погрузчик. Зелёной рамкой обозначил минимальную ширину страницы. Всё кроме оранжевых пятен сделал, но с четырмя оранжевыми пятнами ничего не получается, если делать как фон, то из блока не выходит. Да и все остальные подложки тоже под вопросом, правильно ли реализовано. Код ниже:

https://codepen.io/nomiy/pen/XWWXoMG

```html
<body class="main">
  <section class="about">
    <h2 class="about__title">Выдающийся<br> имидж: гипотезы и теории глазами <span class="about__title-popup"> современников</span></h2>
    <p class="about__text">Повышение жизненных стандартов неестественно экономит селлинг. <span class="about__text-question">?</span></p>
    <p class="about__text">Несмотря на сложности, рекламное сообщество синхронизирует бренд.</p>
    <ul class="about__list">
      <li class="about__item">
        <span class="about__item-big">50 +</span> <span class="about__item-middle">теорий</span><br>среди клиентов
      </li>
      <li class="about__item">
        <span class="about__item-big about__item--background1">30 +</span> <span class="about__item-middle">стран мира</span> охвачены нами
      </li>
      <li class="about__item">
        <span class="about__item-big">15</span> <span class="about__item-middle">лет</span><br>в отрасли
      </li>
      <li class="about__item">
        <span class="about__item-big">1</span> <span class="about__item-middle">день</span><br>на создание имиджа
      </li>
    </ul>
    <img class="about__image-layer1" src="https://svgshare.com/i/FUd.svg" width="778" height="556">
    <img class="about__image-layer2" src="https://svgshare.com/i/FVt.svg" width="485" height="415">
    <img class="about__image-layer3" src="https://svgshare.com/i/FVY.svg" width="438" height="440">
  </section>
</body>
```

```css
.main {
  background-color: #266aa0;
  background: linear-gradient(#266aa0, #081f73);
}
.about {
  width: 1238px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/FU8.svg");
  background-size: 341px 118.44px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 266px top 96px;
  position: relative;
}

.about__title {
  width: 702px;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 64px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: "Didact Gothic", "Arial", sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.about__title-popup {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 40%, transparent 0%);
  background-position: 0 1.22em;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 10px 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.about__image-layer1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: -172px;
}

.about__image-layer2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 136px;
  right: -38px;
}

.about__image-layer3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 30px;
}

.about__text {
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.about__text-question {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fe7338;
}

.about__list {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 36px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.about__item {
  width: 170px;
  margin-right: 155px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.about__item--background1 {
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/FVB.svg");
  background-size: 113px 92px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top -10px left -10px;
}

.about__item:nth-child(even) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.about__item-big {
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.about__item-middle {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае лучше каждую отдельную часть картинки задавать отдельным бэкграундом, так будет легче позиционировать их и управлять при адаптации страницы.

Так же рекомендую, к примеру, оранжевые фигуры вставлять через пвсевдоэлемент (`before/after`) и тогда не придется заморачиваться с обрезанием картинки по краям и позиционированием бэграунда через свойство `background-position`.

[Пример](https://codepen.io/kostyabushuev/pen/wvvMZNm)

Comment: С картинкой из трёх svg не очень понятно как сделать бэкграундом, т.к. видно, что картинка выходит из блока, а бэкграунд этого не умеет.

Comment: И ещё такой момент, что если вместо тега <body> будет тег <main>, тогда для псевдоэлемента z-index: -1 не сработает.

Comment: Не до конца понял, по поводу бэкграундов. У вас есть 4 оранжевых фигуры, одна фиолетовая и техника. Для вас это 6 разных изображений. Достаете их из макета и позиционируете как вам требуется.

По поводу z-index. В вашем случае, если вы заменили на codepen body на main, то просто для псевдоэлемента делаете z-index: 0, а для текста, которорый обернут в спан добавляете position: relative и z-index: 1. В общем здесь с z-index'ом можно поиграться. Тут никаких проблем быть не должно.

Comment: Это я наверное не до конца понял, бэкграунд техники как псевдоэлемент делать (как и оранжевые фигуры)? И кстати техника состоит из трех SVG изображений.

Comment: Можете сделать через псевдожлемент. Можете через тег img и абсолютно спозиционировав его. Тут уже как вам будет удобнее.
Просто эти самые три части объедините в одну картинку и используете.